# Finding Install Date of a NVMe Drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to get the Install Date of a NVMe drive through Python. If we were to do it manually we would have go to properties, details, then "install date" or "first install date". I cannot figure out how to do it via python.
Thank You!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From https://pypi.org/project/pynvme/1.0/:

The pynvme is a python extension module. Users can operate NVMe SSD intuitively in Python scripts. It is designed for NVMe SSD testing with performance considered. Integrated with third-party tools, vscode and pytest, pynvme provides a convenient and professional solution to test NVMe devices.

The pynvme wraps SPDK NVMe driver in a Python extension, with abstracted classes, e.g. Controller, Namespace, Qpair, Buffer, and IOWorker. With pynvme, we can send any NVMe command in Python scripts, with a list of other capabilites:

1. access PCI configuration space
2. access NVMe registers in BAR space
3. send any NVMe admin/IO commands
4. callback functions are supported
5. ...

Since it is designed for NVMe SSD testing and has features to send any NVMe admin/IO commands, this should help in finding install date.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).